# Is there any settings available in AWS Elemental Mediaconvert to remove/mute the audio of the converted videos?

Tags: amazon-web-services, video, aws-media-convert

Currently, the Mediaconvert is configured to create a 720px width video out of a given video. The input video might contain audio tracks. The requirement is to remove/mute the converted video. Hence, the output video should be muted from start to finish.

While browsing, I found, that we can remove audio and video from some parts of the video for inserting Ad content. However, I am unsure whether this works for me or not.

Can anyone point me to any implementations or strategies to achieve the same?

Comment: can you share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes... you have at least two options:
[a] you can remove the default audio track (the container for the audio data) from the Output sections of the MediaConvert job. This will result in the output files having no audio track at all (only video, and optionally subtitles).

[b] If you want the audio track present but muted to silence, you can use the Manual Audio Remixing feature and set the output Gain value to -60 (mute).  This will retain the audio track but with no audible content in it. These files will be slightly larger.

I suggest you experiment with these two options on a short source clip. I am confident one of these methods will work for you.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot, the first method worked fine.